# Improve image quality while using getDrawingCache - android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, image-quality

I am capturing my layout view using `getDrawingCache()` method and creating image from it.
The code works fine and image gets generated, but the problem here is, the generated image quality is very low. I want the resolution of generated image to be high so that whenever i set it to `ImageView` it don't get stretched.

**Here is the code which I am using :**

`RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmp = layout.getDrawingCache();
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`

**P.S. -** I also tried using `layout.buildDrawingCache(true);` and `layout.setDrawingCacheQuality(RelativeLayout.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);` before calling `layout.getDrawingCache();` but no changes in quality were found.

Can anyone please help me out on this, how can I improve quality of the image being generated?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't worked with it, but there is a method called [setDrawingCacheQuality](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheQuality(int)) that might help.

Comment: Did you try to use PNG istead of JPEG? Jpeg compresses image even when quality is set to 100.

Comment: @MalaKa i've also tried calling that method before posting question here. but that too didnt help. Thanks.

Comment: @Salauyou In my case,setting png instead of jpeg decreases  image quality.

Comment: what about `getDrawingCache(true)`?

Comment: @Salauyou that too not affecting any changes to image quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Searching for very long and trying out different solutions, Finally I got the captured Image quality better than it was earlier.

**I changed my code as :**

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
layout.buildDrawingCache(true);
final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache());
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
Canvas c= new Canvas(bmp);


File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
try {

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is what helped me. Hope it'll help others too.